# getting a single row from sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, row

i'm trying to get all rows with a specific date , but it prints nothing. getting all works but specific desn't. it seems that the problem is in this line:
String selectQuery="SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS+ " WHERE "+KEY_DATE+"="+Date ;

i would realy appriciate help.

```
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_PNAME = "pName";
    private static final String KEY_QUANTITY = "quantity";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
// Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_PNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_QUANTITY + " INTEGER," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }
// Getting Specific Contacts
    public List<Contact> getSpecificContacts(String Date) {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
       // String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        String selectQuery="SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS+ " WHERE "+KEY_DATE+"="+Date ;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.set_pName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.set_quantity(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                contact.set_date(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.set_pName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.set_quantity(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                contact.set_date(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }
```

Comment: Probably something to do with how date is stored in your database and how you try to query on it.

Comment: this is how it appears in thw activity:Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
               String mYear = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
               String mMonth =  String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
               String mDay = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
               //String mHour = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
               //int mMinute = (c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))/10;
               //String date=mYear+"/"+mMonth+"/"+mDay;
               String date=mDay+"/"+mMonth+"/"+mYear;

Comment: and then:  // Inserting Contacts
                     Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                     for(int i=0;i<activity.shoppingList.size();i++){
                      boolean tmp=activity.shoppingList.get(i).gotProduct;
                      if(activity.shoppingList.get(i).gotProduct){
                       String p_name=activity.shoppingList.get(i).productName;
                       int p_quantity=activity.shoppingList.get(i).quantity;
                       db.addContact(new Contact(p_name, p_quantity,date)); 
                      }
                     }

Comment: Just add some debugging logging to get the actual string you're testing. Also, you could change the check to name, to if the problem really lies with date or if it's something else.

Comment: SQLite accepts all datatypes, but in reality stores everything as either a String or a Long. In this case you're storing the date as a String. I wouldn't recommend this. I think it's much better to store it as number, e.i. seconds since 1970, and then convert it to a date in your application. I think this is less error-prone and gives more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the mean time i found a different solution.

Comment: @popovitsj Your opinion is just an opinion. There are pros (and cons, of course) in using text dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
String selectQuery="SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS+ " WHERE "+KEY_DATE+"="+Date ;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

instead of using above query use this one

```
String [] columns = new String []{use columns here eg _id, Name,...};
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, columns, KEY_DATE+ "=?", 
new String[] { String.valueOf(Date) }, null, null, null,null);
```